# .vmoptions file content is not being converted into VM parameters.

Tags: install4j

We need possibility to launch our application with custom parameters that should be converted into system properties.
As I understand .vmoptions file content should automatically be added to the existing VM parameters. 
But it is not working. Are there any additional steps required for that?
thanks

Comment: You just put a text file with the same name as the executable and the extension ".vmoptions" into the same directory and add one key-value pair on each line (without the -D prefix). If it does not work, add the contents of your vmoptions file to your question.

Comment: thank you. you are doing great job answering all those dumb questions=)